# 'Session' does not exist in the current context. How can I use it?

Tags: c#, html, session, model-view-controller

i got a problem in using Session. I was following many tutorials and documentations on different sites but still can't figure out how to use Session in my context.

So basically I want to use users login name during the whole session. I've read Session is the thing I need.

Did i forget to import something? Am I using it wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwTMb.png

Can someone please help me with that?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code as text, and [edit] the question to remove thank you notes and replace image with actual text. Also review tags - it is very likely the question should be tagged with either [tag:asp.net-mvc] or [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .NET Core try:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

then

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("test key", "test value");
```

For .NET framework (pre .NET 5) try:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Session["Test key"] = "Test value";
```

Comment: @dimauser Wonderful! Would you mind accepting the answer?